# amCharts: Map Recentering after JSON DataSource Despite Previous chart.homeGeoPoint

Tags: amcharts

I'm mapping a series of points with amChart; after loading the data from an external JSON source, the map re-centers instead of staying at the point I'd set earlier with chart.homeGeoPoint.

I believe I need to use an event listener and set the homeGeoPoint after the map renders the points... but I'm at a bit of a loss; the only events I've found are from dataSource.events, and those appear to be related to fetching/parsing the JSON, as opposed to rendering the map.

```
// Create map instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);

// Set map definition
chart.geodata = am4geodata_region_world_northAmericaLow;

// Set projection
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

// Initial Position / Zoom
chart.homeZoomLevel = 2.6;
chart.homeGeoPoint = {
    latitude: 39,
    longitude: -96.2456
};

// Series for World map
var worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
worldSeries.useGeodata = true;

// Markers

// Create image series
var imageSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapImageSeries());

// Create a circle image in image series template so it gets replicated to all new images

var imageSeriesTemplate = imageSeries.mapImages.template;
var circle = imageSeriesTemplate.createChild(am4core.Circle);
circle.radius = 5;
circle.fill = am4core.color("#116ad6");
circle.stroke = am4core.color("#FFFFFF");
circle.strokeWidth = 2;
circle.nonScaling = true;
circle.tooltipText = "{title}";

// Set property fields
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.latitude = "latitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.longitude = "longitude";
imageSeriesTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";

// Load data        
imageSeries.dataSource.url = "/foo/map-points.php";
imageSeries.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
imageSeries.dataSource.parser.options.emptyAs = 0;

// Center after render
imageSeries.dataSource.events.on("done", function(ev) {
    // This doesn't work - perhaps it is firing too early?
    chart.homeGeoPoint = {
        latitude: 39,
        longitude: -96.2456
    };
});
```

By request, here is a foo.json file for expirmenting with.

```
[{"title":"ISP","url":"\/airport\/kisp\/","latitude":40.7952,"longitude":-73.1002},{"title":"AEX","url":"\/airport\/kaex\/","latitude":31.3274,"longitude":-92.5486}]
```

What do I need to do to make sure the map stays centered on my desired location after the JSON data are loaded and rendered?

Comment: Can you provide sample data so we can test it out?

Comment: I've edited the post to include some JSON data; I was wrong in my initial description of the problem - the re-centering has nothing to do with the content of the JSON data, it just re-centers after the JSON data loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [created an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/765) in regards to why the map re-positions on the `MapImageSeries`' `dataSource` load and how to better work with that. (If you've a GitHub account, please subscribe to the issue.)

In the meantime, presuming the first time your `dataSource` gets its data that the user hasn't moved the map and we want to maintain `homeGeoPoint` as the current center, we can chain events to achieve that.

When the `dataSource` is [`"done"`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/datasource/#done_event) with its data, that doesn't necessarily imply anything has been done on the actual map level. The data still needs to propagate to the `MapImageSeries`, that still needs to create `MapImages` per data item, have the data validated/parsed there, and for whatever reason the map position shifts around. So the first time that happens (using [`events.once`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/#Attaching_events) instead of `events.on`), we then listen for the `MapImageSeries`' [`"datavalidated"` event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mapimageseries/#datavalidated_event) also only one time (because `"datavalidated"` will have run before this, e.g. as soon as you create the `MapImageSeries`, if no data is supplied or it's taking some time, it will still run the event and the `"inited"` event, i.e. I guess you can say the series itself will successfully render nothing).

And to center the map we use `chart.goHome(0);`, this method will zoom to your `homeGeoPoint` and `homeZoomLevel`, the `0` is for how long the animation duration should run, i.e. just do the work, don't animate.

So all that together will look something like this:

```js
// Center after render
imageSeries.dataSource.events.once("done", function(ev) {    
    imageSeries.events.once("datavalidated", function() {
      chart.goHome(0);
    });
});
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/239bfdc8689c65468df32d71b29759b8

Even though the map does re-position once the `MapImageSeries` loads, then it re-centers with the above code, I haven't actually seen the map shift at all anymore. So it looks to me the above code is doing the job of maintaining the `homeGeoPoint`. Let me know if that is still the case once implemented in your application.

Comment: Subscribed to the issue on GitHub to monitor for an actual fix; appreciate the workaround! Thank you!